# Is it possible to overload a constructor that accepts a list in scala?

Tags: list, scala, constructor, constructor-overloading

I am trying to overload the constructor to a class so that it can accept lists of two different types of objects:

```
class myClass(){
  var someStrings: List[String]=List[String]()
  println("hello!")

  def this(strings : List[String])={
    this()
    this.someStrings=strings
  }

  def this(ints: List[Int])={
    this()
    this.someStrings=ints.map(x => x.toString)
  }
}
```

In this case, accept a list of ints or strings, and save a list of strings to the variable someStrings. The code above doesn't work:

```
error: double definition:
constructor myClass: (strings: List[String])myClass at line 12 and
constructor myClass: (ints: List[Int])myClass at line 17
have same type after erasure: (strings: List)myClass
             def this(ints: List[Int])={
             ^
```

Is there a better way of doing this in scala? (Other than taking List[Any] and testing the elements)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create functions on a companion object which do the construction for you in a typesafe way that can be checked at compile time:

```
class myClass(){
  var someStrings: List[String]=List[String]()
  println("hello!")
}

object myClass {
  def fromStrings(strings: List[String]) = {
    val c = new myClass
    c.someStrings = strings
  }
  def fromInts(ints: List[Int]) = {
    val c = new myClass
    c.someStrings = ints.map(_.toString)
  }
}

object Usage {
  val c1 = myClass.fromStrings(List("a","b","c"))
  val c2 = myClass.fromInts(List(1,2,3))
}
```

I would urge you to avoid overloading in general, or checking types at runtime, when you could be checking types at compile-time instead

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the most idiomatic way of doing it (I hope!). I will also take your advice about compile-time checks (i.e. not overloading to start)

Answer (score 2):

That's what `DummyImplicit` is for:

```
def this(strings: List[String])={
  this()
  this.someStrings=strings
}

def this(ints: List[Int])(implicit d: DummyImplicit)={
  this()
  this.someStrings=ints.map(x => x.toString)
}
```

This makes the erased signatures of constructors (i.e. the ones JVM sees) `MyClass(List)` and `MyClass(List, DummyImplicit)`, so the overloading is allowed.

However, as @stew says, it could be a better idea to avoid overloading in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if I want methods with ever more DummyImplicit outputs to build up when I have 3 or more overloaded constructors. I think I will take your and stew's advice to just not do it. It is interesting that this was in the language and why (type erasure rabbit hole).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, another thing you can do is use Arrays. The type information on an array is kept at runtime, so you can do overloading based on the type parameter.

```
class myClass() {
  var someStrings: Array[String] = Array[String]()
  println("hello!")

  def this(strings: Array[String]) = {
    this()
    this.someStrings = strings
  }

  def this(ints: Array[Int])={
    this()
    this.someStrings = ints.map(x => x.toString)
  }
}
```

Arrays are much underused in my opinion

Comment: Clever! I wonder why the Java devs decided that Lists of pointers are not reifiable but arrays of pointers are. (I just tried this on Arrays of strings and arrays of char Lists and it worked for both)

Comment: Because Arrays were 'generic' since the inception of the JVM but type parameters were added in 1.5.